# fast switching using opto coupler

Tags: opto-isolator

i am using optocoupler SFH1690 to shift a pwm of 5V at 20KHz to 12V 20KHz. but it seems that optocoupler wont work on this high frequency. so is there any other faster technique to do so. currently my pwm is no more a pwm at opto's output (because of rise or fall time issues) need help about is going wrong. i have trid it with SFH1690 and 4N24 but same behaviour. resistor with cathode is 470 ohms and i tried with diff values of pull up resistor and cathode resistor but was unable to get a pwm at o/p of optocoupler. instead a slop
[image]

Comment: Same ground on both sides? Why not just one transistor and two resistors?

Comment: If you don't need isolation, do as winny says. If you do, try using a digital isolator.

Comment: As @winny asked, are your two sides actually isolated or is this just a bad schematic?

Comment: At first glance this looked like something worth answering.  Then I read the first word, then the first word of the second sentence.  That's where I quit.  *Screw this*.

Comment: +1 to winny's answer. But if you get the output from collector, you'll get inverted PWM (i.e. Input 1s will be 0s at the output and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept inverting your PWM signal, all you need are one resistor and a transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3DrRD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you must retain the polarity/can't invert it, you need two transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLGXUs.png)</sup>